# Using a Collection in an Entity Framework Query Condition

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a List (of List (of string)). In the inner list, I want the items to be used in an AND. And across the lists, I want these to be ORed together.

For example, my list of lists are as follows:

```
 [
      [red, apple, A],
      [red, apple, B],
      [red, banana, A],
      [red, banana, B],
      [green, apple, A]...
 ]
```

I want the query to search items where:

```
 (category.Contains("red") && category.Contains("apple") && category.Contains("A")) ||
 (category.Contains("red") && category.Contains("apple") && category.Contains("B")) ||
 (category.Contains("red") && category.Contains("banana") && category.Contains("A")) ||
 ... and so on
```

I'm guessing the outer loop will create a UNION of each query, which will have the AND condition for each item of the inner list.

How do I write the loop and Linq statement for this?

Comment: Beg your pardon, but how *one* category can be equal to *three* different values (for instance, *red*, *apple* and *A*)?

Comment: The category field is a string made up of concatenated categories - such as "red|apple|A".

Comment: `list` is `List<List<string>>`: `string[] cats = { "red|apple|A", "red|banana|B" }; var x = cats.Where(c => c.Contains(string.Join("|", list[0])) || c.Contains(string.Join("|", list[1])));`